# How would the field in between two semi-infinite placed next to each other look like?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose two semi-infinite solenoids placed next to each other are separated by a small gap as shown below

[image]

If the solenoids are identical to each other, What would you expect the field in between the solenoids? How would the field look like?

Is it possible that the field lines pass through one solenoid to another without any diversion in between?

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration shown in the sketch, the two fields would be in the same direction, would be nearly uniform in the gap, and would be about the same strength as in each solenoid.  It would bulge outward around the edges.  If one of the solenoids were removed, the field at the end of the remaining solenoid would would be about half the strength of the field inside and well away from the end.  Outside it would spread, and try to loop back around to the other end.

Comment: Can you please sketch it? It would be a great help. Can I think it like two-rod magnets place nearby?

Comment: The magnetic field of a current carrying solenoid is pretty much the same shape as that from a similar cylindrical magnet.  I have not figured out how to post a sketch.  A field line near the edge of the gap would swing out  a bit and then come back in.

Comment: Edit your answer and post it. I get what are you saying but a sketch gives a clear picture.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MJRIBduLHet6Cl71CTL9CDjuuC0ss23k/view?usp=sharing Is this what you mean?

Comment: Only if the gap is large; otherwise the field from the N pole on the right continues across to the S pole on the left with some curvature near the edges.